# Answer as Community wiki: How to change back to normal answer?

Tags: support, answers, community-wiki

If I mark my answer as community wiki and post it, how can I convert it back to a non-community wiki answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have to flag the post for *moderator attention*, requesting that the change is reverted.